# Preloader wont ignore websocket - pace js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, pusher

I added preloader to my website which runs with ruby on rails, it seems it works perfectly, but because of pusher websockets, preloader does not end, it waits all the time, i tried this at my footer,

```
<script>
window.paceOptions = {
    ajax: {
      trackWebSockets: false,
      ignoreURLs: [/pusher/, /heap/]
    }
  }
</script>
```

but it did not work. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think the problem is that you add this in the footer. I think the options need to be set before the pace.js script loads. Seems like it was the problem for me at least, but I'm using ASP.NET and SignalR though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tried this one, it worked. :)

```
Pace.options.ajax.trackWebSockets = false;
```

Comment: Very useful when using online chat widgets.

Comment: Thank you! this has been a proper problem for quite a while