# Pace.js waiting for 101 Switching Protocols

Tags: javascript, pace

I have included pace.js on my html page to show default progress bar.  After reloading page progress bar remains for more than 2-3 mins.  When I had look at developer tool I found that pace.min.js is making request of type 'websocket'.

My question is :

1. Why Pace.js making socket connection request to local host?  ( Please see below image )
2. How to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342595/preloader-wont-ignore-websocket-pace-js solution, but not working.  Still having same issue.

Comment: so you are including pace.js and pace.css provided by pace website? can you update your question with your code

Comment: @moeinrahimi, thanks for your response.  Actually I have downloaded a template from http://www.styleshout.com/free-templates/dazzle/ and I am trying to integrate it in Umbraco site.  I tried to create a stand alone web app to reproduce this issue but I was not able to reproduce.  Now will look into the template and will try to figure it out why pace.js is trying to open a websocket.  Cheers

Comment: I have tested dazzle template and pace is working just fine, maybe it's related to your cms or how you are linking pace

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add something like this:

```
 <script>
      window.paceOptions = {
          ajax: {
              ignoreURLs: ['signalr', '__browserLink', 'browserLinkSignalR'],
              trackWebSockets: false
          }
      };
  </script>
```

before you load the pace.js script. It worked for me.

Comment: Just ignoring `browserLinkSignalR` works for me.