# Rails ActionCable didn't receiving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I have two servers

1. APIs server(Rails & ActionCable)
2. Customer server(Rails 5.1 & Vue js & [actioncable from Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/zh-Hans/package/actioncable))

**on APIs server**:

in app/channels/operation_channel.rb

```
class OperationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
        stream_from 'operations'
    end

    def unsubscribed
        # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
    end
end
```

in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

in config/routes.rb

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

in app/models/operation.rb

```
class Operation < ApplicationRecord
    [...]

    after_update :broadcast

    def broadcast
        ActionCable.server.broadcast "operations", operation: self
    end

    [...]
end
```

**on Customer server**:

in main.js

```
import ActionCable from 'actioncable'

var cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('wss://[APIs server URL]/cable');

var operations = cable.subscriptions.create('OperationChannel', {
    connected: function() {
        console.log("connected");
    },
    disconnected: function() {
        console.log("disconnected");
    },
    received: function(data) {
        console.log('received');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I can only get disconnected callback called when the web-socket server stopping, and I can see web-socket info in the log:

```
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] ...
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
.
.
.
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to operations: {:operation=>#<Operation id: 1,...
```

I have done a lot of research, but still can receive any data from broadcasting and the connected callback never be called too, please help. Thanks

Comment: I figure it out..Everything is working perfectly after removing a javascript module - PACE(Automatic page load progress bars)
I think PACE will handle all the connections so I can't receive any data from the APIs server

Comment: You can set **trackWebSockets** to false to resolve this problem.
reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342595/preloader-wont-ignore-websocket-pace-js)